# Allowing public access to encrypted files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, google-cloud-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is it safe enough to have AES-256-GCM encrypted files publicly available?

We are in the process of designing a system where we can securely grant access to millions of files from a few thousand endpoints. Each file is encrypted with AES-256-GCM using a 256-bit key that is unique to each file. Each file's name is a hex encoding of a SHA-256 hash, so is not practically discoverable. The endpoints will have the keys required to decrypt the files once downloaded, and all communication will be via TLS 1.2+.

We plan to store these files in Azure, AWS, and GCP, starting with Azure Blob Storage. Internally we have a difference of opinion on whether it would be safe to allow public access to these files. Of course we'll disallow listing on the containers/buckets, so someone will firstly need to know the exact name of a file to download it (1 in 2^256). If they happen to download a file, they'll then need to crack a 256-bit key to get to the contents. My feeling is that this is secure enough, but there's still the nagging feeling that we'll have sensitive data open to the public (albeit encrypted).

We take security very seriously, but we can increase scalability quite a lot if we allow the endpoints to get the files directly from cloud storage without having to go through some middleware that does authentication and has a secure back channel to the cloud storage.

Are there any other designs or suggestions we need to consider?
Thanks for the help.

---

Additional info:

- Files are encrypted by the endpoints before uploading using a 256-bit hash of the plaintext (i.e. *convergent encryption*). These hashes/keys are kept on the endpoints themselves.
- File names are `SHA256(SHA256(PlainText))`

  - While you could theoretically use that to discover whether a file with a certain hash is present, we only store files of at least 64KiB in size so it's not practical to brute force the discovery process.
- The reason for using our own middleware is just because it matches our existing model, where files are stored on local disks behind the middleware instead of cloud storage.
- It doesn't **have** to be public, but it would simplify things greatly if we didn't need to manage and exchange SAS tokens if it didn't add any *real* security.

Comment: What is the SHA-256 a hash of? Is it the plaintext or the cipher text, or something else?

Comment: Is there are reason you're considering your own middleware rather than an S3 access key? Does adding an access key have a major impact on scalability for you?

Comment: SAS tokens will add real security.. I am not sure why you are saying that.. SAS can be auto generated after user is authenticated, That will add huge REAL security.

Comment: Sure, SAS tokens definitely do add security in the general sense. But if the existing files cannot feasibly be decrypted, does it matter if someone got their hands on it? I know it doesn't feel right that someone got access to the file, but is it any different to them getting a TLS stream dump?

Answer (score 2):

If the filename is a hash of the plaintext, then this system makes it trivial to ask "does the following document exist?" If the number of likely documents of a given size is small, than I can just SHA-256 hash all of those documents and then check if it a file of that name exists. I don't have to worry about the encryption step. This can be resolved by ensuring that the SHA-256 filename is a hash of the *encrypted* document. This also has the advantage of being self-authenticating, and avoiding collisions if two documents have identical contents but different keys.

You already have good authentication in GCM. Unless you're making use of this redundant authentication by having the accessor check the hash prior to decryption, you may be better served using UUIDs as the filenames rather than SHA-256. You would get the same benefits of uniqueness, randomness, and sparseness for lower computational cost.

Deciding how to build this system relies a great deal on the nature of the "few thousand endpoints." Do they all have the same access? To all documents? Does their access change over time?

This matters because you should think of the filename+key as an access token, very similar to whatever credential you would add through middleware. If the endpoints store the filename and key together (which seems extremely likely), then the encryption isn't actually doing much for access control. It's just adding an extra 32 bytes to your access token.

The reasons to add AES-GCM are integrity (validating that the file hasn't been modified) and protection at rest and in transit. Adding AES-GCM helps if someone accidentally reconfigures the bucket to allow file listings, for example. So that's nice.

So the final question is whether there's a value to adding an intermediate broker, and if so, how. Adding custom middleware seems an invitation to create security bugs without adding much actual security. But I believe all the systems you've described have a request authentication system with either a shared secret or per-endpoint credential. If it doesn't introduce a lot of performance impact, it feels like an obvious addition.

Whether it's worth eating a performance impacts depends on how much control it would give you. If your endpoints are all controlled by you and all share the same credentials, then an extra layer isn't doing a lot. But if they're third-parties, and you gave each their own credential, then it's a very nice tool to cut off a client who is behaving badly (or perhaps compromised). The key here is that you need to plan around how you would make use of that. Just adding more and more layers doesn't create better security. The layers each need to have a clear goal that you actually make use of.

- UUID/Encrypted-hash names give you basic authentication. (Absolutely necessary)
- AES-GCM gives you assurance of file integrity and protection at rest and in flight. (Probably useful)
- Per-endpoint authentication token gives control to reject an endpoint. (But only if you have processes to revoke access.)
- Custom middleware gives power to add additional controls than cloud provider's auth. (But only if you have specific controls in mind.)

Answer (score 1):

You might assume it is secure (at least for some time) , but it breaks multiple security principles..

1. Security in layers.
2. Assumption of security.
3. Tracing and Monitoring.
4. Key management

And I do not know

1. Why does it have to be public?
2. Why don't you use the shared access signatures know as SAS.
3. How do you manage and trace the keys?
4. Do you have risk analysis ?
5. Do you have a mechanism to rotate keys?
6. Do you have plan B?

In Summary, I would not encourage you to do that although it may look secure enough..
Each situation has exceptions and rationales, and I would understand if you have thought of all aspects. But I know for sure this is not the best option available.
I also would consider another type of encryption like Hybrid or digital.